# Generating Rows from Values in Several Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have approx 11 million rows with 21 columns as so:

```
area_id_number, c000, c001, c002 ...
01293091302390,    2,    2,    0 ...
01293091302391,    2,    0,    0 ...
01293091302392,    3,    1,    1 ...
```

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
value_id, area_id_number, value_type
       1, 01293091302390, c000
       2, 01293091302390, c000
       3, 01293091302390, c001
       4, 01293091302390, c001
       5, 01293091302391, c000
       6, 01293091302391, c000
       7, 01293091302392, c000
       8, 01293091302392, c000
       9, 01293091302392, c000
      10, 01293091302392, c001
      11, 01293091302392, c002
 ...
```

I haven't been able to find a method do this yet.  I've looked at unpack/pivot/deaggregate (couldn't find the right solution with any of these terms...)

A second part of this question is, will I have any memory issues?  Are there any efficiency things I should be considering?  I should end up with around 140 million rows from this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I hope my edit improve the question.  Btw, it is an xy problem!  I'm going to generate random points w/in these geometries. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main process is calculated by `ndarray.repeat()`, I have not enough memory to test 11M rows, but here is the code:

create the test data first:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create sample data
nrows = 500000
ncols = 21

nones = int(70e6)
ntwos = int(20e6)
nthrees = int(10e6)

rint = np.random.randint

counts = np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype=np.int8)
counts[rint(0, nrows, nones), rint(0, ncols, nones)] = 1
counts[rint(0, nrows, ntwos), rint(0, ncols, ntwos)] = 2
counts[rint(0, nrows, nthrees), rint(0, ncols, nthrees)] = 3

columns = ["c%03d" % i for i in range(ncols)]
index = ["%014d" % i for i in range(nrows)]

df = pd.DataFrame(counts, index=index, columns=columns)
```

Here is the process code:

```
idx, col = np.where(df.values)
n = df.values[idx, col]
idx2 = df.index.values[idx.repeat(n)]
col2 = df.columns.values[col.repeat(n)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id":idx2, "type":col2})
```

Comment: HYRY, this works nicely.  It is far beyond my programing level, I will do my best to learn from it.  Thank you.